# find orthonormal basis for a planar 3D ( possibly degenerate) polygon

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Given a general planar 3D polygon, is there a general way to find the orthonormal basis for that planar polygon?

The most straight forward way to do it is to assume to take the first 3 points of the polygon, and form two vectors each, and these are the two orthonormal basis vectors that we are looking for. But the problem for this approach is that these 3 points may line on the same line in the polygon, and hence instead of getting two orthonormal vectors, we get only one.

Another approach to find the second orthonormal vector is to loop through the polygon and find another point that forms a different orthonormal vector than the first one, but this approach is susceptible to numerical errors (e.g, what if the second vector is almost the same with the first vector? The numerical errors can be significant).

Is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cross product of any two lines connected by any two vertices. If the cross product is too low then you're in degenerate territory.

You can also take the centroid (the avg of the points, which is guaranteed to lie on the same plane) and do pick the largest of any two cross products of the vectors from the centroid to any vertex. This will be the most accurate normal. Please note that if the largest cross product is small, you may have an inaccurate normal.

If you can't find any cross product that isn't close to 0, your original poly is degenerate and a normal will be hard to find. You could use arbitrary precision or adaptive precision algebra in this case, but, of course, the round-off error is already significant in the source data, so this may not help. If possible, remove degenerate polys first, and if you have to, sew the mesh back up :).

Comment: *You can also take the centroid* -- I think this is the problem here: without knowing the orthornomal basis there is no way to project the polygon in 2D, and hence there is no way to find the centroid.

Comment: You don't need to project anything onto 2D. You can find the 3D centroid simply by averaging the points.

`pt->x=0;
pt->y=0;
pt->z=0;
for (n=0;n<npoints;n++) {
 pt->x+=p[n]->x;
 pt->y+=p[n]->y;
 pt->z+=p[n]->z;
}


pt->x/=npoints;
pt->y/=npoints;
pt->z/=npoints;`

Now pt is your centroid in 3D.

Comment: You can use an orthogonal best plane fit algorithm to figure out the plane. The implementation can be a pain however. Try [Wm5ApprPlaneFit3.cpp](http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Approximation/Approximation.html) or [bestfit.cpp](http://codesuppository.blogspot.com/2006/03/best-fit-plane.html). Please note, however, that the internal implementation may also be subject to inaccuracies, so it may not solve your problem. If your points are collinear (and you didn't check), no algorithm in the world can figure out the normal of your plane, because it's not plane, it's a line...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ott but one way would be to compute the covariance matrix of the points, and then diagonalise that. If the points are indeed planar then one of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix will be zero (or rather very small, due to finite precision arithmetic) and the corresponding eigenvector will be a normal to the plane; the other two eigenvectors will span the plane of the polygon.
If you have N points, and the i'th coordinate of the k'th point is p[k,i], then the mean (vector) and (3x3) covariance matrix can be computed by

```
m[i] = Sum{ k | p[k,i]}/N (i=1..3)
C[i,j] = Sum{ k | (p[k,i]-m[i])*(p[k,j]-m[j]) }/N (i,j=1..3)
```

Note that C is symmetric, so that to find how to diagonalise it you might want to look up the "symmetric eigenvalue problem"

Comment: can you be more specific about this? What is `k` and `p` ?

Comment: k is just a loop counter; for example by Sum{ k | p[k,i]} I meant p[1,i] + p[1,i] + .. + p[N,i] ie the sum of the i'th coordinates of the points. As noted in my answer, p[k,i] is the i'th component of the k'th point that defines the polygon.